# Android start ActionBarActivity shows empty page first

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-support-library

I'm using support library 4 and 7. I'm starting an activity by intent. That is an [ActionBarActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.java), android.support.v7.app.actionbaractivity.

The problem I'm having is when I start and show a new activity. Before my activity shows, I get a blank activity with an android logo like this. It was hard to get the pictures but I think it illustrates clearly enough the issue.

**How do I get rid of this behavior?**

The problem is illustrated bellow.

1) My new activity is starting to load.

[image]

2) My new activity is nearly loaded.

[image]

3) My new activity is loaded. The android icon is now gone.

[image]

I start an activity this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is how my configuration looks like in the manifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.blah.bli.activities.SomeActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/tidsam_logo"
        android:label="@string/empty_title"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The activity code.First, most of them inherit from this class because I need a log out function and for that I need to keep track on when the user was last active. Nothing strange bellow I think.

The acitivty is big, does a lot of things

```
public class SuperActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    ApplicationExtension appState;

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction(){
        appState.LastActive = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         appState = ((ApplicationExtension )getApplicationContext());
         appState.LastActive = Calendar.getInstance();

    }


}
```

This is one simple activity that has the issue.

```
public class HelpActivity extends SuperActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

        setActionBar();
    }

    // todo: create actionbar util class
    private void setActionBar() {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
        TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abs_layout_login);
        login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        FontUtils.applyFontAwesomeToControl(this, findViewById(R.id.abs_layout_back));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == null) return;

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.abs_layout_back:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show com.blah.bli.activities.SomeActivity code

Comment: As per request I added an example of one of the activites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Android uses the Theme you set in the manifest to create a "dummy" activity untill your application is loaded.

Setting an custom theme in your manifest will load an dummy activity in the same style as the rest of the application and makes it less noticable.

Here a tutorial how to do this: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/